# Should I replace _outpw() function?

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, conio

I have some problems when I do simulation for my Simulink program, it says

> `_outpw() function not defined`

Should i try to find some other function to replace it?

I have put this head source (`conio.h`) in the Matlab folder, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Formatting of the output (in this example) could support the readability. Take a minute and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @guenhter which output?

Comment: `_outpw() function not defined`

Comment: _outpw and associated instructions are low level instructions to output to ports.  It cannot be used on Windows programs.  You need to find out why your simulation program is trying to output directly to a port or what is causing it to generate the command

Comment: You Should tell us more about how you did try to put things together. Have you followed a given tutorial? *Some problems when I do simulation* is not something very accurate. Take time to reformulate and re-read [ask]. Don't hesitate to edit your original post with more information.